# Slider Maximum value = textbox1.text

Tags: c#, winforms, slider

I looked all over Google can no one asked this question or there isn't any answer for this. What i am trying to do is to make a `slider`'s maximum value the text in my `textbox`, i have tried to to do this:

**This code is in my `textBox1_TextChanged` Event**

```
textBox1.Text = slider1.Maximum.ToString();
```

and this:

```
this.slider1.Maximum = textBox1.Text;
```

And some other ones but it doesn't work, it says:

```
Cannot Implicitly Convert 'String' to 'Int'
```

If anyone knows how to do this please post it here or show me where i can find the code.

---

**Second Problem**

I have another problem, i have this code:

```
private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = slider1.Value.ToString();
    }
```

It shows up the value of the slider just fine but the slider piece that you grab stays at the end, if this is too confusing here is my problem:

When i grab the slider the text in textBox1 is the slider's value.
The problem is is that the slider part that you grab to change the value stays at the end. does anyone know how to show the grabber part at the real value instead of the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx):

```
int sliderValue = 0;
Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out sliderValue);
```

And if try parse fails provide an error message explaining why..

Comment: Thanks, that worked, can you please see if you can fix my 2nd edit to my question?

Comment: You should start a new question if you're having further problems

Answer (score 2):

You can find here by using `Parse` or `TryParse`

```
this.slider1.Maximum = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

But for more corrective and make your input is alway a number, use `TryParse`:

```
int maxValue;
int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out maxValue);
```

Comment: Goes without saying that this will crash if you put anything other than an number in the textbox...

Answer (score 0):

```
const int defaultMaximumSlider = 0; // Default value for slider maximum
int value;

if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value)) //Try to get our value
{
    this.slider1.Maximum = value;
}
else // and if it isn't successful assign our default
{
    this.slider1.Maximum = defaultMaximumSlider;
}
```